# Is there a option to add a new row in shinobi grids?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grid

First of all i am using shinobicontrols for developing interactive UI controls (Grids) for iOS using Objective c and please don't suggest me some other controls as an answer because i need to use only this.

I am half way stuck while using this control. i have downloaded demo code for grids provided by shinobicontrols (trial for 30 days). from : http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobigrids/product-tour/get-started-quickly-and-easily/

I was able to reorder rows and columns, edit contents of cell, re size column width by pinch gesture and much more.

But i couldn't add a new row or column to the existing grid. Just wanted to know whether this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the datasource (add/remove) item and just do [grid reload];

I think this should do.

Comment: Yeah!! it seems this will work. give me some time i will try it now and will be back.

Comment: thanks, Its working for me @itsdamslife! but i was searching for any predefined method in the document, which can serve the purpose. anyways i am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer seems to be correct. Adding my views Shinobi grids can be considered as UITableView cells, If you simply change the data source array of the tableview and call `[tableview reloadData]`, number of cells displaying on the view will also change. There is no option to add a row still.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this one](https://github.com/poksi592/DataGUIControls). It is in alfa stage, but it will be quite a powerful in month or two, I would say. Any suggestions are welcome and it's free, of course. Number of rows and row content is fully controlled from delegate, so it is dynamic.